# Can anyone explain why this error occurs? (a==2) is already true here

Tags: java

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a=2;
        char b,c,d;
        b = (a<2)? 'f' : 'g';                   //1
        if(a<2) c = 'h'; else c = 'i';          //2
        if(a<2) d = 'j';                        //3
        if(a>2) d = 'k';                        //4
        if(a==2) d = 'l';           //5
        System.out.println(b+","+c+","+d);      //6

    }  
}
```

> Example.java:12: error: variable d might not have been initialized

Comment: If none of your `if` conditions are true, you are still printing `d`, which had no value set to it.  You need to set a default value for a local variable if it is possible you attempt to access it before it has a value set to it.

Comment: but a==2 is true....isn't it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `char`s but the fact that it's possible for `d` to stay uninitialized

Comment: @SashinSahasra yes, but the compiler doesn't know that

Comment: @Sashin The compiler does not know that your final `if` will always be executed, if you use an `else` then you would not have an issue, because either `if` or `else` would always be executed and the compiler can confirm that.

Comment: but I cannot understand that why compiler doesn't know that a==2 is true.

Comment: @SashinSahasra because `a` is a variable and might take any value. `a == 2` is evaluated at run-time and not compile-time.

Comment: but I have used variables for if conditions on other programs...they worked well....but this program is not working like that....why is that...

Answer (score 2):

In case of b and c you are using if-else due to which compiler is sure that some value will be assigned to b and c before the print statement. But in case of d compiler is not sure whether any of the if conditions will be true and d will be initialized or not.

Comment: but (a==2) is true according to this program. Then why the compiler doesn't initialize the variable to d?